# i want to use 'this' in the cartDetails(),but show Uncaught TypeError

Tags: jquery

```
function cartDetails(){
    //generating product id
    var arry = $(`this`).parents('a').attr('href');
    var newArry = arry.split('=');
    var prodId = newArry[1];
    //generating imageName
    var imgArry = $(this).closest('#items').find('img').attr('src');
    var newImg = imgArry.split('/');
    var imgName = newImg[1];
    //generating model
    var model = $(this).parent().find('p').text();
    //generating price
    var prePrice = $(this).parent().find('span').text();
    var price = parseInt(prePrice);
    return [imgName,model,price];
}
$('.btn-success').click((e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    cartDetails();
})
```

Comment: `catDetails.apply(this)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about your HTML content but you must pass the jQuery object to your function to be able to find elements.

See https://jsfiddle.net/c5ys8L02/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function cartDetails($btn) {
      //generating product id
      var arry = $btn.parents('a').attr('href');
      console.log(arry)
      var newArry = arry.split('=');
      var prodId = newArry[1];
      //generating imageName
      var imgArry = $btn.closest('#items').find('img').attr('src');
      var newImg = imgArry.split('/');
      var imgName = newImg[1];
      //generating model
      var model = $btn.parent().find('p').text();
      //generating price
      var prePrice = $btn.parent().find('span').text();
      var price = parseInt(prePrice);
      return [imgName,model,price];
  }

  $('.btn-success').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(cartDetails($(this)));
  })
});
```

if it is any close or any help. There is though lot to improve in the HTML as well as the Javascript side but maybe it helps you out.

If you could, please always add jsfiddle or some other place to your questions to actually try it out. And as always, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Did you check out the fiddle? Maybe you could create similar from scratch to see also your HTML code where you try to fetch data from the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

- `this` in a function may not refer to the desired element .. So you'll need to pass an argument to the function

Here is how it works

```js
function _function_1(){
  console.log('function Without argument the id is: ' + $(this).attr('id'));
}
$('button').on('click' ,function(){
  _function_1();
});

function _function_2(el){
  console.log('function With argument the id is: ' + $(el).attr('id'));
}
$('button').on('click' ,function(){
  _function_2(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="BUTTON">Test Click</button>
```

- Id should be unique (Don't use same id for more than one element) that means `$(this).closest('#items')` is not right it should be `$('#items')` while you should have just one element with id `items` OR use classes instead `class="items"`

Then your code should looks like this

```
function cartDetails(el){
    //generating product id
    var arry = $(el).parents('a').attr('href');
    var newArry = arry.split('=');
    var prodId = newArry[1];
    //generating imageName
    var imgArry = $(el).closest('.items').find('img').attr('src');
    var newImg = imgArry.split('/');
    var imgName = newImg[1];
    //generating model
    var model = $(el).parent().find('p').text();
    //generating price
    var prePrice = $(el).parent().find('span').text();
    var price = parseInt(prePrice);
    return [imgName,model,price];
}
$('.btn-success').click((e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    cartDetails(this);
})
```